# How to scrape data from a web form faster with all cases from drop down menu with selenium and python

Tags: web-scraping, batch-processing

I made a script to scrape marriage registration records from my gov website using selenium and python but i have to scrape data for all office locations (600) in my state for 3 years (1800 locations)

I made a script to get data from that form for one place for one year which is time consuming. I currently batch replaced input areas in my script with name and year and made 1800 .py files and running them 10 at a time manually. Is there any way to speed it up.

Here’s my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

import time
import csv
import os
import codecs

options = Options()
options.headless =  True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")

print('loading')


########################### SETUP ###########################
startNo = 1                                                 # <
location = "Arani_Chennai North"                            # < ENTER HERE
year = 2015                                                 # <
########################### SETUP ###########################

fileName = (f'RECORDS_HINMAR_{location}_{year}.csv')        #




driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://tnreginet.gov.in/portal/')

time.sleep(5)
print('navigating to form')

en = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fontSelection"]').click()

more = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="1195002"]/a')
search1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="8500020"]/a')
hovmarr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="90000403"]/a')
 

Hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(more).move_to_element(search1).move_to_element(hovmarr)
Hover.click().perform()


time.sleep(3)

try:

    for x in range(startNo,2000): #################################################################### RESET ######-----1

        print('__________START__________')
        mType =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmb_marrType"]').send_keys("Hindu Marriage")
        searchBy =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Search_Criteria_Two"]')
        Hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(searchBy)
        Hover.click().perform()
        Office =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cmb_sub_registrar_office"]').send_keys(location) #CHANGE  --- 2
        RegNo =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="RegNO1"]').send_keys(x)
        Year =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Year"]').send_keys(year) #CHANGE YEAR  ------------------------------ 3


        submit =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CopyOfMarriageSearch"]/div[2]/div/div[18]/input')
        Hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(submit)
        Hover.click().perform()
        print('Loading reg no:        ', x )
        time.sleep(6)
    #EXTRACT DATA FROM TABLE
        print('Extracting data')
        Res_re =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MarriageMstListDisp"]/tbody/tr/td[1]').text
        Res_hus =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MarriageMstListDisp"]/tbody/tr/td[2]').text
        Res_wife =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MarriageMstListDisp"]/tbody/tr/td[3]').text
        Res_wPar =driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MarriageMstListDisp"]/tbody/tr/td[8]').text
        print('-----------------------')
        print(f'|     {location}                 | {Res_wife}')
        print('-----------------------')
        print('start csv write...')
                    #CSV FILE NAME
        with codecs.open(fileName, mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as RECORDS_file: #CHANGE FILE NAME  ----------------------- 4
            
                employee_writer = csv.writer(RECORDS_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

                employee_writer.writerow([x, Res_re, Res_hus, Res_wife, Res_wPar])

                print('Write to CSV success !')
                print('**********END**********')

except:
    print('error in', x)
    driver.quit()
    print('opening', fileName)
    path = os.path.normpath(f'C:\\Users\\Shyam\\Documents\\{fileName}')
    os.startfile(path)
```

Answer (score -1):

To improve the speed you can use Multi thread.

My friend implement multithread into my scraping, but i dont know how can i use it.

Here is my code:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/javix64/web_scraping_vinted2.0/master/testing2.py

Importing

```
import threading
```

Using multithread

```
def request_thread(start_page, middle_end_page, results_array, lock):
    print('I am thread number %s'%(threading.current_thread().name))

    lock.acquire()
    #Here we put our code
    # we want the thread to get the 27 pages and returns the results into a variable, last thread will get less
    thread_name = threading.current_thread().name
    # page request
    #go into loop for scraping all json pages
    for i in range(start_page,middle_end_page):
        vinted_json = web.get(main_url+str(i)).json()
        try:
            #getting the data from json and saving into csv
            for value in vinted_json["items"]:

              res = []
              res.append(str(value["id"]))
              res.append(str(value["title"]))
              res.append(str(value["brand_id"]))
              res.append(str(value["size_id"]))
              res.append(str(value["status_id"]))
              res.append(str(value["disposal_conditions"]))
              res.append(str(value["user_id"]))

              results_array.append(res)
        except:
             mamon=1
    print("Length is: " + str(len(results_array)))
    lock.release()
```